# Is it possible to overwrite a file with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, file, stream, sftp, overwrite

I am developing SFTP server with nodejs and I am writing a file which contain some code errors.

Here's my code :

```
    readfile(path, writestream, fileError) {

    if (path === '/put.error') {

        if (fileError) {

            console.warn("Dowloading : " + path);

            var data = JSON.stringify(fileError, null, 4);

            writestream.write(data);

            console.warn("File downloaded")
        }

        writestream.end();

        return true;
    }

    writestream.end();
    return true;
}
```

It works fine the first time I did "get put.error" but I got an issue when I wanted to do download it again because the file already exist. How I could overwrite this file ? 
I don't need to keep old datas, just to destroy it or overwrite.

Comment: Why don't you look if it's there and delete the file if it is? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlinksync_path

Comment: Ok ill try this

Comment: Did deleting the file first work for you?

Comment: I am trying but I am in trouble to get the path of file.. I mean I passed it but the method always return "false"

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path that is returning false? And you are sure that it is there?

Comment: I tried this `fs.unlinkSync("/Users/stagiaire/Downloads/put.error");` But I can't get the file. I copied the path on the file directly and I got this error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'UsersstagiaireDownloadsput.error'` because it can't get the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156672/discussion-between-hermanthegermanhesse-and-cupkek05).